# Variable host IP address in iptables rule

Tags: iptables, nat, openvz

I am running CentOS 6.4 with OpenVZ on my laptop. In order to provide Internet access for the VEs I have to apply the following rule on the laptop:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source <LAPTOP_IP>
```

It works fine.

However, I have to work in different places - office, home, partner's office etc. The IP of my laptop is different in those places, so have to alter the rule above each time I change place.

I have created a workaround which basically determines the IP and applies the rule:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$(ifconfig | awk -F':' '/inet addr/&&!/127.0.0.1/{split($2,_," ");print _[1]}')
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source $IP
```

The workaround above works. I only still have to execute it manually. Perhaps I could make it a hook executing whenever my laptop obtains an IP address from DHCP - how can I do that?

Also, I am just wondering if there is an elegant way of getting it done in the first place - iptables? Maybe there is a syntax allowing to specify "current hardware ip addres" in the rule?

Answer (score 4):

Use `-j MASQUERADE` (taken from [CentOS docs](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/System_Administration_Guide/postrouting-ipmasquerading.html)):

> To allow LAN nodes with private IP addresses to communicate with
>   external public networks, configure the firewall for IP masquerading,
>   which masks requests from LAN nodes with the IP address of the
>   firewall's external device (in this case, `eth0`):
>
> ```
> [root@myServer ~ ] # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> ```
>
> This rule uses the NAT packet matching table (`-t nat`) and specifies
>   the built-in `POSTROUTING` chain for NAT (`-A POSTROUTING`) on the
>   firewall's external networking device (`-o eth0`).
>
> `POSTROUTING` allows packets to be altered as they are leaving the
>   firewall's external device.
>
> The `-j MASQUERADE` target is specified to mask the private IP address
>   of a node with the external IP address of the firewall/gateway.

It was meant for uplinks which don't have static ip addresses.

Comment: Thank you fuero, that is almost what I wanted. However, it is not always `eth0` that is used to connect to the Internet. Right at this moment I am using `wlan0` and your solution worked with `eth0` replaced by `wlan0`. Is there any way I can specify something like `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <CURRENT_INTERNET_INTERFACE> -j MASQUERADE`?